# XMLType out parameter and ODP.NET

Tags: c#, odp.net, xmltype, out-parameters

I try using XMLType column in my table and ODP.NET.

any full sample source code using ODP.NET and XMLTYPE out parameter?

My procedure:

```
PROCEDURE GET_DATA_DEPLOY(pPROYECT IN VARCHAR2,
                  pETIQ IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                  pMOMENT OUT TIMESTAMP,
                  pDATA OUT XMLTYPE)
```

And for testing: function and procedure.

```
FUNCTION FRKDATA_GET_XMLTYPE(num IN NUMBER, xml1 IN XMLTYPE) RETURN XMLTYPE IS
  xmlout XMLTYPE;
  BEGIN
  SELECT XMLTYPE_COL 
  INTO xmlout
  FROM POC_TEST_XML_TABLE
  WHERE NUM_COL = num;
  RETURN xmlout;
  END FRKDATA_GET_XMLTYPE;


PROCEDURE FRKDATA_TESTXML(qry in VARCHAR2, rslt OUT XMLTYPE) AS
BEGIN
 rslt := dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype(qry);
END FRKDATA_TESTXML;
```

View in https://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/454750

I get "connection is closed" errors

Only, I've found this sample, but without OUT parameters.

```
/*
create or replace function xmlproc(v1 in xmltype) return xmltype is
begin
return v1;
end;
/
*/

using System;
using System.Data;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Types;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection())
        {
            con.ConnectionString = "user id=scott;password=tiger;data source=orcl";
            con.Open();
            using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("",con))
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "xmlproc";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("return", OracleDbType.XmlType)).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("v1", OracleDbType.XmlType)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                cmd.Parameters["v1"].Value = "<a>b</a>";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Console.WriteLine(((OracleXmlType)cmd.Parameters["return"].Value).Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Alex Keh from Oracle, The below works for me.

```
PROCEDURE "XMLPROC" (  "PARAM1" OUT XMLTYPE) IS
BEGIN
  PARAM1 := dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype('SELECT FIRST_NAME FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID=100');
END;


OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
con.ConnectionString = conString;
con.Open();
OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "xmlproc";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("xmlout", OracleDbType.XmlType)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Console.WriteLine(((OracleXmlType)cmd.Parameters["xmlout"].Value).Value);
```

Any version source code using Enterprise Library?

References: https://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/454750